# CumulusCI 'utf-8' error

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, cumulusci

When I try to run command like `cci service connect github` I've received error `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`. I am working on WSL. CumulusCI version: 3.44.1. Python version: 3.8.10.
Weird error, because on CumulusCI 3.43.0 and Python 3.8.10 one mate has the same issue, and second not. Maybe someone has met that issue?

Answer (score 3):

*I am on the CumulusCI team at Salesforce.org*.

This issue almost certainly indicates that your local repository contains a critical file (probably `cumulusci.yml`) that is not correctly saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Most text editors, including Visual Studio Code, can save files in UTF-8. In Visual Studio Code, click the encoding name in the status bar at the bottom of the window and click "Save with Encoding", then choose UTF-8.

If this does not solve the problem, please file a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/CumulusCI/issues) with the complete traceback (`cci error gist`) and the other information requested by the issue template.

Please note that we do not officially support WSL, nor does `sfdx`.

Comment: After `cci error gist` I received the same error. Here is post with traceback - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358526/cumulusci-error-utf-8
If you can see there, I will be grateful.